# Chromium pass message to popup extension even if it is not active

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension. I am able to pass a message from background page to popup extension when a context menu is clicked if i open the popup page with "Inspect pop-up" selection. Because it stays open in this way.

But if I click the context menu when the popup page is not opened, no message received by it.

Do you have any suggestions to open popup automatically, make it stay open or send message to it when even if it is not active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to pragmatically open a popup window. Popup windows are only active when the popup is open which is why you cant send messages to it when it is closed.

You could either queue messages in the background page and have them retrieved the next time the popup window is opened. Or depending on the functionality you might look into using [HTML5 desktop notifications](http://beakkon.com/tutorial/html5/desktop-notification) instead.

Comment: I should follow your first suggestion. How can I queue the messages?

Comment: However you want. You could create an array of messages in memory or maybe localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending stuff to the popup, the popup should request what it needs when it is opened.

Because the popup is just an HTML page, it doesn't exist until it has been opened.

Basically, like abraham mentioned, you would store any information in the background, using `localStorage` or `chrome.storage`. When the popup opens, it should then use the `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()` function to get a reference to the background, which can provide access to the stored information.

If you are using `localStorage` or `chrome.storage`, you may be able to access it directly, without using the background, as storage is shared across the whole extension.